# Using less Timers

Tags: java, multithreading, timer, delay, priority-queue

It doesn't really lag that much in my game but I know that I could reduce a lot of lag in my game by having less `Timer`'s running. The game have multiple `Timer`'s because it have one `Timer` that updates everything like the players location and all the obstacles then I have other `Timer`'s that I use to remove the power ups that you could get.

For example I have one `Timer` that have it's initial delay set to 5000 and when it is runned one time (it will only run one time) it will remove a specific power up and the I have another `Timer` that have it's initial delay set to 20 000. How would I keep the different delay of each timer but still only using one or at least fever than I use now?

Is there anyway that I could use `PriorityQueue` or `ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor` to accomplish this? and if so how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would `schedule` tasks on the `ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor`, and then re-schedule them for a different delay if you want to run the same task again.

Another option is to use a `DelayQueue` to store the tasks you want to execute, and use a separate thread to `take` and execute runnables off of the queue.  As with the `ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor` you'd have to put the runnables back on the queue with a new delay if you want them to run again.

The `ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor` lets you schedule tasks to continually run after a fixed delay, whereas the `DelayQueue` requires you to keep putting the task back on the queue after it's run.

Answer (score 0):

Why would there be a timer that "updates everything"? Updating should always execute non-stop. (Unless you want to limit your game to constant FPS) 
You really should consider abusing the "Game Loop":

```
While Game Is Running
    Update() 
    Draw() 
End While
```

If you don't want any lags in your game, you need to consider always updating player location, etc...
That said, when you update locations, etc... you need to make sure you make them relative to the time elapsed since last time Update() was executed.

If you're not constantly calling Update(), then you're going to have lags no matter what threading pattern you use.